# Construir query sql en base a un filtro aplicado con ComboBoxes en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Os hago esta pregunta para ver si alguien puede darme ideas sobre cómo podría construir una query en sql en función de unos combobox que pueden tener algo seleccionado o no. Le he estado dando vueltas al tema y hacerlo usando sentencias `if..else` no es lo más óptimo en mi caso, ya que dispongo de 6 comboboxes donde puede haber algo seleccionado o no. Creo que debe haber una manera más óptima que montar 36 ifs para construir la query. Os pongo un ejemplo de lo que quiero decir:

```
    Private Function filteredQuery() As String

    Dim sql_ As String
    Dim divisionSelected_ As Boolean = False
    Dim areaSelected_ As Boolean = False
    Dim paisSelected_ As Boolean = False
    Dim versionSelected_ As Boolean = False
    Dim mesSelected_ As Boolean = False
    Dim anioFiscalSelected_ As Boolean = False

    If Cb_Divisiones.Text <> "" Then
        divisionSelected_ = True
    End If

    If Cb_Area.Text <> "" Then
        areaSelected_ = True
    End If

    If Cb_Paises.Text <> "" Then
        paisSelected_ = True
    End If

    If Cb_Versiones.Text <> "" Then
        versionSelected_ = True
    End If

    If Cb_Mes.Text <> "" Then
        mesSelected_ = True
    End If

    If Cb_AnioFiscal.Text <> "" Then
        anioFiscalSelected_ = True
    End If

    sql_ = filteredQuery2(divisionSelected_, areaSelected_, paisSelected_, versionSelected_, mesSelected_, anioFiscalSelected_)

    Return sql_

End Function

Private Function filteredQuery2(divisionSelected_ As Boolean, areaSelected_ As Boolean, paisSelected_ As Boolean, _
                                versionSelected_ As Boolean, mesSelected_ As Boolean, anioFiscalSelected_ As Boolean)

    Dim sql_ As String

    If divisionSelected_ = True And areaSelected_ = True And paisSelected_ = True And versionSelected_ = True And mesSelected_ = True _
        And anioFiscalSelected_ = True Then
        sql_ = "SELECT * FROM Registros WHERE Division = '" & Cb_Divisiones.Text & "' AND Area = '" & Cb_Area.Text & "' AND Pais = '" _
            & Cb_Paises.Text & "' AND Version = '" & Cb_Versiones.Text & "' AND Mes = '" & Cb_Mes.Text & "' AND AnioFiscal = '" _
            & Cb_AnioFiscal.Text & "'"
    ElseIf divisionSelected_ = True And areaSelected_ = True And paisSelected_ = True And versionSelected_ = True And mesSelected_ = True _
    And anioFiscalSelected_ = True Then
        ...
        ...
    End If

    Return sql_

End Function
```

Utilizo 2 funciones, una para establecer el `true` o el `false` a los booleanos en base a si hay algo seleccionado en el ComboBox, y otra para construir la query en base a los booleanos. Puede ser una tontería usar 2 funciones pero me sirve para encaptsularlo un poco más y que no me queden funciones enormes.

Se os ocurre alguna manera más óptima de construir una query en base al valor que hay en varios filtros (en mi caso un ComboBox por cada filtro)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solución final en base a la idea que me ha dado @gbianchi:

```
    Private Function filteredQuery()

    Dim sql_ As String = "SELECT * FROM Registros WHERE "

    If Cb_Divisiones.Text <> "" Then
        sql_ += "Division = '" & Cb_Divisiones.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If Cb_Area.Text <> "" Then
        sql_ += "Area = '" & Cb_Area.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If Cb_Paises.Text <> "" Then
        sql_ += "Pais = '" & Cb_Paises.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If Cb_Versiones.Text <> "" Then
        sql_ += "Version = '" & Cb_Versiones.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If Cb_Mes.Text <> "" Then
        sql_ += "Mes = '" & Cb_Mes.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    If Cb_AnioFiscal.Text <> "" Then
        sql_ += "AnioFiscal = '" & Cb_AnioFiscal.Text & "' AND "
    End If
    'End If

    sql_ += "Enabled = '" & True & "'"

    Return sql_

End Function
```

Con esto puedo comenzar la query pidiendo que me traiga todos los registros que coincidan con las condiciones que pongo en el `where`. Luego por cada uno de los combos, si tiene texto (no importa el tipo de texto, simplemente un string de caracteres), lo incluyo en la query con un `AND` al final para poder seguir concatenando. Como en mi tabla tengo una columna llamada `Enabled` para controlar si el registro ha sido o no eliminado de la aplicación en algún momento, al final de la query incluyo siempre la condición

```
sql_ += "Enabled = '" & True & "'"
```

y devuelvo la query ya montada.

Gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: Por mas que hayas escrito el codigo asi, en este caso tu respuesta es solo codigo y no explica nada de nada. Que hace filteredQuery1? que le aporta a todo el proceso? para que sirve pasar un monton de variables booleanas que no hacen nada a filteredQuery2? Esto hace lo que vos queres, pero que ganaste haciendo dos metodos?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Además con lo que me dices me he dado cuenta de que con lo nuevo que he puesto basándome en tu idea, ahora filteredQuery1() ya no tiene sentido, así que se puede eliminar del proceso. Voy a editar la respuesta para dejarlo bien y más claro. Gracias de nuevo!

Answer (score 1):

Podrias construir el where agregando de a una las clausulas

```
Dim where as string
If Cb_Divisiones.Text <> "" Then
    where += Division = '" & Cb_Divisiones.Text & "' AND '
End If
```

**Siempre hay que tener cuidado con los espacios al armar asi.**

Pero esto tiene un problema, el problema del AND final (o las comas, o los separadores).

Y aca es cuando uno tiene que ponerse creativo. Como sacarlo, si es que existe.

Tengamos en cuenta que puede no existir, porque puede que yo hayamos tenido ninguna selección (digo puede, porque no conozco las reglas de tu problema)

Entonces, tratemos de mejorar esto.

El where lo dimensionamos de otra forma:

```
Dim where as string = " WHERE "
If Cb_Divisiones.Text <> "" Then
    where += Division = '" & Cb_Divisiones.Text & "' AND "
End If
```

y al agregarlo a la query, verificamos 2 cosas. Si mide mas que el tamaño que le pusimos originalmente, y ahi sacamos el AND final

```
....
Dim sql_ As String = "Select ....."
....
If len(where) > 7 Then
    'Existe un where que agregar
    where = mid(where,1,len(where)-5)
    sql_ += where
End If
```

Lo que hacemos aca, es sacarle al where los ultimos 5 caracteres (que son el AND y los espacios) y construimos nuestra query.

Tene en cuenta que es mejor siempre pasarle los parametros, como parametros, depende de que base de datos uses eso cambia.

Comment: Me has dado una idea muy buena jugando con el where. Voy a editar mi código para poner lo que he hecho basándome en tu idea. Muchísimas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada. Pero no entiendo cual es la diferencia con tu solucion, que sigue usando montones de variables y sigue comprobando todos los check varias veces. Vos pediste mejorarlo, y no se como tu codigo mejora lo de arriba. De donde salio enabled? Como puede ser un campo de texto?